# How to pass 'blocking' to getStaticPaths with TypeScript in Next.js?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I would use `fallback: 'blocking',` for my Next.js page, but TypeScript refuses it. Has the latest 12.2.0 Next.js. What is wrong?

```
Type '() => Promise<{ paths: any; fallback: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticPaths<ParsedUrlQuery>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ paths: any; fallback: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticPathsResult<ParsedUrlQuery> | Promise<GetStaticPathsResult<ParsedUrlQuery>>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ paths: any; fallback: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<GetStaticPathsResult<ParsedUrlQuery>>'.
      Type '{ paths: any; fallback: string; }' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticPathsResult<ParsedUrlQuery>'.
        Types of property 'fallback' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | "blocking"'.
```

and the code:

```js
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
// ...
    const paths = res.data.map((organizationAndPostId: string) => ({
        params: {
            organizationShortId: organizationAndPostId[0],
            postId: organizationAndPostId[1],
            tempUserShortId: organizationAndPostId[2],
            imgId: organizationAndPostId[3],
        },
    }))

    let ret = {
        paths,
        fallback: 'blocking',
    }
    return ret
}
```

I think problem is with `"` or `'`. But VSCode automatically converts it to `'`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the type error because when you declare the `ret` object, TypeScript assumes `fallback` to be of type `string` rather than being the literal string `'blocking'`. In other words, internally the `ret` object gets typed as follows, which is incompatible with the expected `GetStaticPaths` type.

```js
const obj: { 
    paths: { 
        params: { category: string; }; 
    }[];
    fallback: string; // `GetStaticPaths` expects this to be of type `boolean | 'blocking'`
}
```

To fix the issue, you can either return the object directly, without the intermediate variable.

```js
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
    //...

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: 'blocking'
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, cast the `fallback` value to a `const` to force the literal string type on it.

```js
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
    //...

    let ret = {
        paths,
        fallback: 'blocking' as const,
    }
    return ret
}
```